# Decision trees vs Oblique decision trees

Tags: decision-trees, terminology

What are oblique decision trees ?

What are the differences between them and classic decision trees ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An oblique decision tree is a decision tree in which the conditions used to split the data put a constraint over a linear combination of the features.

Say that you have a dependent variable $Y$ that you wish to explain  using the features $X_1, \dots, X_d$. In a typical decision tree, the nodes will only check the value of a single feature (e.g. $X_1 > \mu_{X_1}$) whereas in an oblique decision tree, the nodes will check whether a linear combination of a number of features is smaller or larger than a certain quantity (e.g. $2X_1 + 3X_2 > \mu_{X_1, X_2}$)

The term used to talk about decision trees that only check the value of a single feature per node is *axis-aligned* decision trees. This is because each of the hyperplanes used to perform the splitting is perpendicular to a certain axis/feature. For instance, the hyperplane that splits the data points into those fulfilling the condition $X_1 > \mu_1$ and those who don't will be defined by the equation $(E): X_1 = \mu_1$ and will be perpendicular to the axis $X_1$.

In general, an oblique condition can be expressed as follows:
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^{d}w_iX_i \space + \space w_{d+1} \space < \space 0
$$

where $w_1, \dots, w_{d+1}$ are real numbers representing the weights of each feature.

As you could have probably guessed, axis-aligned decision trees can be thought of as a special case of oblique decision trees in which all the weights $(w_i)_{i \in [1,d]}$ are equal to $0$ except for one.

A major difference between axis-aligned decision trees and oblique decision trees lies within the possible number of conditions on which to perform the split. In the former, the number of all possible conditions/splits is at most $d.n$ where $d$ is the number of dimensions and $n$ is the number of data points. In the latter, with the weights being real numbers, there is an infinite number of possible splits to pick from. This difference plays a key role in defining the kind of algorithms used to build each type of these decision trees.

For further reference:

[*OC1: A randomized algorithm for building oblique decision trees.*](https://sites.bu.edu/phenogeno/files/2014/06/oc1-conference.pdf)

*[A System for Induction of Oblique Decision Trees](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/9408103.pdf)*

*[Inducing Oblique Decision Trees With Evolutionary Algorithms](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3418739_Inducing_oblique_decision_trees_with_evolutionary_algorithms)*